# convert Mathematica expressions to Matlab (ToMatlab and Bessel functions)

Tags: export, matlab

I have several expressions like the two followings:

```
    X11 = I omega rho0 phi HankelH1[m, k0 ra];
    X12 = -b1 kp1^2 BesselJ[m, kp1 ra];
```

I want to covert these expressions to Matlab. To this end, I use the package [ToMatlab](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/577/) 
(by the way is there somewhere available a more recent version of it?)

```
X11 // ToMatlab
X12 // ToMatlab
(* "sqrt(-1).*omega.*phi.*rho0.*HankelH1(m,k0.*ra);
" *)
(* "(-1).*b1.*kp1.^2.*BesselJ(m,kp1.*ra);
" *)
```

However, this is not the syntax that Matlab uses of the Bessel and Hankel functions. For instance `BesselJ[m,x]` (Mathematica) => `besselj(m,x)` (Matlab).

Any ideas how to overcome the problem and avoid modifying on my own the latter expressions?

Comment: a quick fix could be `... // ToLowerCase`. But I don't know Matlab enough to assess how general it is.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it. I hove more general expressions but for the moment I don't see any problem with your fix.

Comment: Why not to export the expression in `C` or `Fortran` format, and import it to Matlab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could modify the ToMatlab package.

Find the section starting with

```
(*** Symbols *****************************************************************)
```

then add

```
ToMatlabaux[BesselJ] = "besselj"
ToMatlabaux[HankelH1] = "besselh"
```

In these cases the translation was trivial. Only the function name needed to be changed. When the argument order needs changing too, modify the section starting with

```
(*** Special cases of functions **********************************************)
```

For example, for the two-argument form of [`ArcTan`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcTan.html), add

```
ToMatlabaux[ArcTan[x_, y_]] := "atan2(" <> ToMatlabaux[y] <> ", " <> ToMatlabaux[x] <> ")"
```

This will set up a new rule for `ArcTan`, in addition to the existing one that handles the single-argument form.