# Mathematica to Matlab

Tags: export, conversion, matlab

my question is a duplicate of :
[Is it possible to export the equations from Mathematica to MATLAB?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14035/is-it-possible-to-export-the-equations-from-mathematica-to-matlab)

I did some symbolic calculations in Mathematica and want to transfer the result to Matlab. The  [ToMatlab](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/577/)-package is exactly what I need, but sadly it has some flaws, e.g. with atan2.

So, does anybody know a working alternative to the ToMatlab package?

### EDIT:

Seems like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165929/convert-mathematica-expressions-to-matlab-tomatlab-and-bessel-functions) is also closey related

### UPDATE:

Sadly the provided answer is not working for me. Actually most of the functions under

```
(*** Special cases of functions ************
```

are not working for me. E.g.

```
ToMatlab[Log[10, 3]] ==> log(3).*log(10).^(-1);
ToMatlab[Power[E, 2]] ==> exp(1).^2;
```

Comment: I think your best bet is editing this package (I put the `atan2` example at the end of [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/166162/12) after your email). But maybe someone has already updated it and will answer here.

Comment: Thanks again. I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug fixed version of ToMatlab:

https://pastebin.com/TcjErHVT

Comment: Does it fix the problem the OP mentioned, i.e. how `ArcTan[x,y]` is translated?