# Adding Greek letters to ToMatlab

Tags: packages, matlab

I want to add Greek letters to the ToMatlab package. The most recent publicly available version I found is [here](https://github.com/ianwilliamson/ToMatlab).

There is a section on symbols starting on line 242. I tried adding a line
`ToMatlabaux[\Phi] := "phi"`
and several similar variations. None of which worked. Any ideas?

I've read the prior discussions and found [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165929/convert-mathematica-expressions-to-matlab-tomatlab-and-bessel-functions) most useful but still not quite what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if I make a definition like this:

```
ToMatlabaux[Global`\[Phi]] := "phi";
```

You have to be explicit about the context of the symbol inside the package, which also points out a limitation (that it will only work on global phi's).

I can take care of all Greek letters at one go, if I change the definition of `ToMatlabaux[e_Symbol]` to

```
ToMatlabaux[e_Symbol] := StringTrim[Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX[e],"\\"]
```

But I would test it thoroughly. It might have unintended consequences.

Use `StringDelete` with an appropriate pattern, if you want mult-letter symbol names to have Greek letters replaced by their Latin names:

```
StringDelete[Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX[\[Phi]\[Alpha]], 
 Whitespace | "\\"]
```

Comment: Thanks. There was a similar line in there already 
```ToMatlabaux[e_Symbol] := ToString[e]``` that did not work (at least not in Mathematica 14).

Comment: @Roy Yep, that's the line I changed to the above.